# Does malloc takes care of memory allignment?

Tags: c, malloc, system-calls

I allocated 5 bytes of memory using malloc and I was able to use those 5 bytes to store characters or integers.
For example,use the first byte to store a character and the next four bytes to store an integer.
How does malloc takes care of memory allignment issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc)

> If allocation succeeds, returns a pointer to the lowest (first) byte
>   in the allocated memory block that is suitably aligned for any object
>   type.

So the memory block is aligned for any object type.

> use the first byte to store a character and the next four bytes to
>   store an integer.

That's not valid. You need to either bundle the char and integer together in a structure (which might include padding) or have 2 separate memory blocks for them. Or serialize them (which is another issue).

Comment: Why is it not valid?

Comment: Get the address to the second byte.
typecast it and then use it to store an integer.
It is working.

Comment: @HarikrishnaPatibandla it is Undefined Behavior. The fact that it seems to work it's irrelevant.